# $φ_t : \mathbb{R}^3[x] → \mathbb{R}^3[x]$ is a linear transformation: $φ_t(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d) = (a - bt)x^3 + (dt^2 - c)x$. Find $im φ_5$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

$φ_t : \mathbb{R}^3[x] → \mathbb{R}^3[x]$ is a linear transformation of the form:
$$φ_t(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d) = (a - bt)x^3 + (dt^2 - c)x$$
where $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is the parameter. Determine the bases of space $ker φ_3$ and $im φ_5$.

Now, I did simillar exercises, but never in the field of polynominals.

So I thought to do that in a similar manner. For $im φ_5$ I get:

$$φ_5(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d) = (a - 5b)x^3 + (25d - c)x $$
$$φ_5(a, b, c, d) = (a - 5b, 0, 25d - c, 0) = (a, 0, 25d, 0) + (-5b, 0, -c, 0)$$

\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 25 & 0 \\
    -5       & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

after some transformations I get:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

So (1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1) is a basis of $im φ_5$? If I got $im φ_5$ right I think I can do $ker φ_3$ as well. So, is that right?

Comment: You can indeed just work with $\varphi_t(a,b,c,d)=(a-bt,0,dt^2-c,0)$ from $\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^4$. However, I'm wondering how you got that matrix? If you're trying to write down a matrix which represents $\varphi_5$, then this should be a $4\times 4$ matrix. Note that $(0,1,0,1)$ cannot be in the image of $\varphi_t$ for any $t$.

Comment: As I said, I have no idea how to do that, I was just looking for similarities between this case and the other ones that I have already solved. In the matrix 4 x 4 there would be the 2 rows that I have included in my matrix? What about the other 2?

Comment: I don't think either of those rows will be in the matrix. You can make the matrix with respect to any bases, but I'm assuming you're just using the standard basis. In this case, the columns of the matrix are $$\varphi(1,0,0,0),\varphi(0,1,0,0),\varphi(0,0,1,0),\varphi(0,0,0,1)$$

Comment: Ok, now you got me totally lost. So how do I use information from the exercise (about linear transformation) and that standard matrix?

Comment: The matrix I described in my previous comment is just the matrix of $\varphi$ with respect to the standard basis. You can write down this matrix, row reduce, and from the RREF form you can read off bases for the kernel and image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just work with $\varphi_t(a,b,c,d)=(a-bt,0,dt^2-c,0)$ as a map $\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^4$; but you should convert your final answers back to polynomials.

The matrix of $\varphi_t$ with respect to the standard basis has $$\varphi(1,0,0,0),~ \varphi(0,1,0,0),~ \varphi(0,0,1,0),~ \varphi(0,0,0,1)$$ as the columns, i.e.
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 &-t & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & t^2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

You can row reduce this (with $t=5$ if you want), and from there you can determine bases for the kernel and image.